# PHP Date display as time ago

Tags: php

Does anyone know how I can change this date format to time ago rather than DD/MM/YY

```
<?php the_time('M j, Y') ?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function for that: [`human_time_diff()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/human_time_diff/). Use it like so: (`U` because we want the unix timestamp)

```
<?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U') ); ?>
```

If you want additional text, you can use the following

```
<?php printf (esc_html__('%s ago', 'yourlanguageslug'), human_time_diff(get_the_time('U'))); ?>
```

Comment: Hi @kero, how do I add "ago" on to the end of this?

Comment: @JordanKellett Please see my update

Comment: Ah right, so I add both lines of code?

Comment: @JordanKellett You can add either line, just using the bottom one is fine!

Comment: Hmm, the bottom one only seems to display the "&s ago" when I add it into the php for some reason.

Comment: Do you have `&` in your code? It needs to be `%`. Alternatively you could use `<?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U') ) . __(' ago', 'yourlanguageslug'); ?>`